# How to scroll audio graph in EZAudio in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording, visualizer, ezaudio

I am using EZAudio library to record/play audio and plotting a graph with it's Rolling plot type. I want to make it scrollable so that I can go to specific portion of recording. Right now it is appending the new recording at the end but it is also deleting it from start. Please help...